# Does "Android Go" supports "PWA Installation"

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

Just wanted to know if "Android Go" supports "PWA Installation"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Progressive Web Apps are designed to work on any platform and to be "installable" from the browser. So they will work on Android Go.
[More info](https://web.dev/what-are-pwas/)

Comment: thank you Veesar, is there a way why I cant have the add to home screen message or even the install option when I click the 3 dots on chrome (latest) for android 10 Go?

Comment: I have installed Chrome and Firefox but still no "install" or add to home screen option

Comment: @bryankimartificio What device is this? And what launcher? It could be because the launcher doesn't support it. Try changing the launcher, restart and check if you have the option.

Comment: I really apricate your comment @veesar! please see link for the exact android https://www.fravega.com/p/tablet-x-view-proton-titanium-colors-max-10-32gb-2gb-ram-20006368/, thank you!

Comment: @bryankimartificio the link doesn't provide info about the launcher used on the tab. You might want to try changing the launcher as mentioned. See [this link](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/change-replace-your-androids-home-screen-app-0210061/) on how to do that.

Comment: thank you, we will try to ask the users if there were possible an install launcher, and if not will try to install 1, I will let you know if it works :) thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 3):

I spent days trying to understand why Mozilla's example PWA (https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/a2hs/) didn't show the install button on a Tablet with Android 11 GO in Google Chrome, until I saw @veesar's comment to change Launcher (https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/change-replace-your-androids-home-screen-app-0210061/) and the install button appeared. The Launcher that was on the Tablet was Quickstep, so I switched to Microsoft Launcher and Apex Launcher and in both PWA was installed. Thanks!